# enviar correo con java

Tags: java, gmail, javamail

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Properties propiedad = new Properties();
        propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

buenas tardes tengo el siguiente codigo en java el codigo en algunas computadoras si funciona bien pero en otras me marca el siguiente error alguien sabe a q se debe tengo un servidor proxy puede ser el

Mensaje de error:

> ```
> GRAVE: null javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
>
> nested exception is: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1960) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:196) at mailer.panel.jButton1ActionPerformed(panel.java:132) at mailer.panel.access$000(panel.java:24)
> ```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que marca?

Comment: GRAVE: null
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1960)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:196)
 at mailer.panel.jButton1ActionPerformed(panel.java:132)
 at mailer.panel.access$000(panel.java:24)

Comment: hola este es el error q me marca

Comment: Los mensajes de error son fundamentales, por favor ponlo en la pregunta misma pulsando en [edit], no en un comentario. En cuanto al error, ¿tienes algún antivirus o firewall que quizá esté bloqueando el puerto?

Comment: Intenta también cambiar esto: `propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");` por esto: **`propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");`**  en caso de querer usar Gmail sin iniciar sesión.

Comment: hola A. Cedano la red tiene un proxy y un antivirus kaspersky endpoint pero no se me este bloqueando el puerto